How to estimate the integral?
Let matrix $\mathbb{W} = \mbox{diag}\{ a_1,\cdots,a_{n} \}$ with $0\le a_j \le 1$ for all $j$.
Let $m,n\ge 1$ and $m \le n$.  I want to estimate the following integral
$$
       I : =     \frac{1}{|B_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}(0,1)|}  \int_{B_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}(0,1)}   \left( x^T \mathbb{W} x \right)^{\frac{m}{2}} \, dx.
$$
I guess there exists $C>0$ independent of $m,n$ such that
$$
 \frac{1}{C} \left( 
    \frac{1}{n} \, \mathrm{Tr}(\mathbb{W})  \right)^{\frac{m}{2}} \le I  \le C \left( 
    \frac{1}{n} \, \mathrm{Tr}(\mathbb{W})  \right)^{\frac{m}{2}},
$$
where Tr$(\mathbb{W}) = \sum a_j$ is the trace.
As an Example, if all $a_j=1$, then by polar coordinate one can easily sees that $I = \frac{n}{n+m}$, as desired.
Moreover, by multinomial theorem, I can (only) prove it under very special conditions (the proof is a little lengthy and I could post it if someone interests):
$$
(1) \  m \le \log n, \quad (2) \ a_j \ge \delta>0.
$$
But I think it should be right without any extra assumptions. And can we explain it by probability theory like math expectation or concentration-compactness of the measure?

If $m=1$, by the reverse Minkowski inequality (here $p=\frac{1}{2}$)
$$
|B_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}(0,1)| \cdot I = \int_{B_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}(0,1)}   \left( x^T \mathbb{W} x \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \, dx  =   \left\| \sum a_j x_j^2 \right\|_{L^{p}}^{p} \ge \left( \sum a_j \left\| x_j^2 \right\|_{L^{p}} \right)^p.
$$
Note that
$$
\| x_1^2\|_{L^{p}} =  \left( \int_{B_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}(0,1)} |x_1| \, dx \right)^2 \sim \frac{|B_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}(0,1)|^2}{n}.
$$
We obtain the desired lower bound.  One can also prove the upper bound by Minkowski inequality if $2\le m \le C$, i.e. for any fixed $m \ge 2$.


How should I interpret $x\mathbb{W}x^{\top}$ when $\mathbb{W}$ is a $n\times n$ diagonal matrix and $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$? I guess you mean $x^{\top}\mathbb{W}x$ (using the usual convention of treating vectors as column vectors) and the dimensionality of $x$ is $n$ instead of $2n$?

I have fixed it.

1. Write $B = B_{\mathbb{R}^n}(0, 1)$ for short. Also, let $J$ denote the OP's integral:
$$ J
= \frac{1}{|B|} \int_{B} (x^{\top}\mathbb{W}x)^{m/2} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$
In order to simplify this integral, we may invoke the coarea formula. Let $\sigma$ denote the surface measure of $\partial B$, and let $\overline{\sigma} = \frac{1}{|\partial B|} \sigma$ be the normalized surface measure (and hence a probability measure). Then by using the relation $|\partial B| = n|B|$,
\begin{align*}
J
&= \frac{1}{|B|} \biggl( \int_{0}^{1} r^{m+n-1} \, \mathrm{d}r \biggr) \biggl( \int_{\partial B} (\omega^{\top}\mathbb{W}\omega)^{m/2} \, \sigma(\mathrm{d}\omega) \biggr) \\
&= \frac{n}{n + m} \biggl( \frac{1}{|\partial B|} \int_{\partial B} (\omega^{\top}\mathbb{W}\omega)^{m/2} \, \sigma(\mathrm{d}\omega) \biggr) \\
&= \frac{n}{n + m} \int_{\partial B} (\omega^{\top}\mathbb{W}\omega)^{m/2} \, \overline{\sigma}(\mathrm{d}\omega)
\end{align*}
So by the Jensen's inequality, for $m \geq 2$,
\begin{align*}
J
&\geq \frac{n}{n + m} \biggl( \int_{\partial B} (\omega^{\top}\mathbb{W}\omega) \, \overline{\sigma}(\mathrm{d}\omega) \biggr)^{m/2} \\
&= \frac{n}{n + m} \biggl( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \int_{\partial B} \omega_i^2 \, \overline{\sigma}(\mathrm{d}\omega) \biggr)^{m/2} \\
&= \frac{n}{n + m} \biggl( \frac{\sum_i a_i}{n} \biggr)^{m/2},
\end{align*}
where the last line follows by the symmetry.

2. Consider the case $m = n$. Also set $a_1 = 1 - \frac{n-1}{n^2}$ and $a_2 = \ldots = a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$. Then
\begin{align*}
J
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\partial B} \biggl( \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{n}\biggr)\omega_1^2 + \frac{1}{n^2} \biggr)^{n/2} \, \overline{\sigma}(\mathrm{d}\omega) \\
&\geq \frac{1}{2} \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{n}\biggr)^{n/2}
\int_{\partial B} |\omega_1|^n \, \overline{\sigma}(\mathrm{d}\omega) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{n}\biggr)^{n/2}
\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}.
\end{align*}
It is not hard to check that this lower bound is asymptotically $e^{-1/2}2^{-n}$ as $n \to \infty$. On the other hand,
$$ \biggl( \frac{\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbb{W})}{n} \biggr)^{n/2} = \frac{1}{n^{n/2}} $$
decays much faster than $2^{-n}$. Therefore it is impossible to bound $J$ by a constant multiple of $\left( \frac{\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbb{W})}{n} \right)^{n/2}$ uniformly in $m \leq n$ and $\mathbb{W}$.

In general, for any $2 \leq m \leq n$ and for any $\mathbb{W} = \operatorname{diag}(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ with $a_i \geq 0$ for all $i$,
$$ \frac{n}{n + m} \biggl( \frac{\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbb{W})}{n} \biggr)^{m/2} \leq J \leq \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)\Gamma(\frac{m+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{m+n}{2}+1)\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})} \operatorname{Tr}(\mathbb{W})^{m/2}. $$
Moreover,

The lower bound is achieved when $a_1 = a_2 = \ldots = a_n$, and

The upper bound is achieved when $a_i > 0$ for exactly on $i$.



Assume $a_n = \mbox{max}_j a_j$ , the maximizer of the sum $\sum a_j x_j^2$ on the sphere
$\sum x_j^2 =1$ should be $x=(0,...,0,1)$, since $\sum a_j x_j^2 \le a_n$.

@cbi, Oops, my mistake. You are right!

In the limit step lim${m \rightarrow \infty}$, since $n\ge m$, I'm not sure the limit is max${x \in B}$.

@cbi, My bad, I failed to realize there is such a restriction on the values between $m$ and $n$. I'll think about it!

Ok. Anyway, the lower bound (Jensen's inequality) is enlightening!

Could  you explain the meaning of $\mathbf{E}$ or give some reference?

@cbi, It is expectation symbol, but I decided not to use the language of probability in my latest revision.

Good! How can u get the general upper bound ? What if we assume $m \le \log n$?

@cbi, The upper bound, corresponding to the integral $$\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbb{W})^{m/2} \frac{1}{|B|} \int_{B} |x_1|^m , \mathrm{d}x, $$ can be computed by a standard method. (This bound is exact because it its realized by some choice of $a_i$'s.) This is further bounded above by an expression of the form $$C\left(\frac{m}{ne}\right)^{m/2},$$ which is sharp as $m, n \to \infty$ (for example, as $n\to\infty$ with $m=\log n$) up to a constant multiplication factor.

I just found that "Reverse Minkowski inequality in $L^p$ space" may be used to give the desired lower bound when $m=1$, taking $p=1/2$.
